# How to call in the loop twice redirect

Tags: oracle-apex

I've got a button made that calls for such a redirect when you press it:

```
javascript:window.open('f?p=&APP_ID.:0:&SESSION.:APPLICATION_PROCESS=test:NO:P6_MY_TEXT:&P6_MY_TEXT','_blank');
```

Now I'd like to call the code like this a couple of times from the multiselection list, so that the file save window will show X times. So far I have the code as below, but there is only one window to save the file, and in the console you can see that the loop has passed twice.

```
let tab = apex.item("P6_LIST").getValue();
tab.forEach(function(element){
    console.log(element);
    javascript:window.open('f?p=&APP_ID.:0:&SESSION.:APPLICATION_PROCESS=test:NO:P6_MY_TEXT:&P6_MY_TEXT','_blank');
})
```

Comment: 1) What version of APEX are you using? 2) In your example, you don't seem to be using `element` in the loop. Is that just because you're testing, or do you need to pass something from `element` in the URL? 3) Based on your comment to Salim, it sounds like you want to open windows one at a time, right? If so, please update your question to reflect that. 4) Finally, you're opening up new tabs. Is that what you want or have you considered opening modal pages instead? Modal pages may provide a better user experience.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, browsers will not allow opening multiple windows at once unless you make sure that popup was not blocked.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. I wish it were like this:
- you show the first window to save the file, save the file, the window closes
- a second window to save the file is shown, saves the file, the window closes
- and so on